# When building a class library, what is the best practice to return to a calling procedure if my class method encounters a fatal error?

Tags: .net, class, exception

So let's say I build a class with methods that may result in a fatal exception, such as network failure.  Is it best practice to:

1) Throw an exception and let the calling procedure trap and handle it?
2) Raise a class event for which the calling procedure has added a handler?
3) Suppress the exception and return False or Nothing from the method rather than the intended result?

My apologies if this is an irritatingly trivial question. I'm new to .NET

Comment: Do u means u build a class then some other class call method from that class, if there's an exception, the method will return the exception for the caller know and trap or handle it ?

Comment: yes. I was trying to figure out whether to let the exception occur, or suppress it and just return a "False" result from the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather go with option 1.

Provide as much information in the exception as possible, and let the caller handle the exception.
Further to this, you should also try to rethrow the exception (or not catch it in the first place) so that the caller might receive the original message and stack trace.

You should almost never swallow an exception without the caller knowing of it.

From [Exceptions and Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)

> Do not catch an exception unless you can handle it and leave the
>   application in a known state. If you catch System.Exception, rethrow
>   it using the throw keyword at the end of the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

All are popular approaches in some sense, though returning nothing, also known as failing silently, is quite dangerous.

I would think about how I want the library to be used, by actually writing client code. That would give a good indication of whether an exception or a handler is better.

Answer (score 0):

I thinked of this when I built a WCF Service to return to client error when there're exceptions in my code.

I studied my code and defined the error which can occur into error code and error message
And my method will return an Int errorCode when exception or error occur to client.

The client will use another method in my Service to know what error is.

Example Code :

```
public string GetError(int error)
        {
            switch (error)
            {
                case 1:
                    _errorString = Constants.ERR_INVALID_INFORMATION;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    _errorString = Constants.ERR_DELETE_FAILED;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    _errorString = Constants.ERR_ADD_FAILED;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    _errorString = Constants.ERR_UPDATE_FAILED;
                    break;       
            }
            return _errorString;
        }
```